# How to use ALT of the image to fire jquery click event

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following image in my asp.net page:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgExpCol" AlternateText="plus" ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl="~/theImages/subTaskPlus.png" runat="server" CssClass="imgExpCol" />
```

The following in my JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on('click', "#imgExpCol", function () {
        alert("test");
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskMinus.png");
        $(this).attr("alt", "minus");
    });
    $("body").on('click', "#imgExpCol", function () {
        alert("test2");
        $(this).attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskPlus.png");
        $(this).attr("alt", "plus");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
});
```

When the plus is clicked, it expands the TR and displays the minus. When the minus is clicked, it collapses the TR and displays the plus.

If I am using the current `#imgExpCol`, both event fires off. I am using different ALT text for the two image. How can I use the ALT text rather than the ID?

Comment: Use one event handler and check the current `alt` in that handler.

Comment: and unless the image is loaded with AJAX, there is no need to attach the event handler to the body

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `alt` attribute in your selector, so your JS would become:

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on('click', "#imgExpCol[alt=firstalttext]", function () {
        alert("test");
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskMinus.png");
        $(this).attr("alt", "minus");
    });
    $("body").on('click', "#imgExpCol[alt=secondalttext]", function () {
        alert("test2");
        $(this).attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskPlus.png");
        $(this).attr("alt", "plus");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
});
```

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gxta4vL9/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use a single click handler and use a condition to know the `alt`. Depending on the condition, do something.

```
$("body").on('click', "#imgExpCol", function () { //Is delegation really needed here?
//$("#imgExpCol").on('click', function () {
    if($(this).attr('alt') === 'plus'){
        alert("test");
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskMinus.png");
        $(this).attr("alt", "minus");
    }else{
        alert("test2");
        $(this).attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskPlus.png");
        $(this).attr("alt", "plus");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    }
});
```

**Performance tip :** Cache `$(this)` into a variable. It will prevent you to create x number of jQuery objects.

Comment: And remove the body event if the image exists on load of the page

Answer (score 1):

It's not good to bind two events, insted use class to figure out status of element.

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on("click", "#imgExpCol", function(){
        var t = $(this);
        // check if is expanded
        if(t.hasClass("expanded"))
        {
            t.attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskPlus.png");
            t.attr("alt", "plus");
            t.closest("tr").next().remove();
            t.removeClass("expanded");
        }
        else
        {
            t.closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
            t.attr("src", "../theImages/subTaskMinus.png");
            t.attr("alt", "minus");
            t.addClass("expanded");
        }
    });
});
```